# shortcode add custom message depending on order status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a shortcode which allows me to write in another page a message, depending on the current order status.

**Here is the code I am trying:**

```
add_shortcode( 'order_status_custom', 'wpc_orderstatus_shortcode');
function wpc_orderstatus_shortcode( $atts, $order_id ) {

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $data = '';
if ( $order->has_status('completed') ) {
    $data= "4";
} elseif( $order->has_status('on-hold') ){
    $data ="3";
}elseif( $order->has_status('processing') ){
    $data ="2";
}elseif( $order->has_status('pending') ){
     $data= "1";
}
    return $data;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show your shortcode implementation?  How are you passing the `$order_id` to the shortcode?

Comment: I wasn't passing it! It is still displaying the error when I add `$order_id = new WC_Order($post->ID);`

Comment: you can't pass a variable to a shortcode in the way you're trying to do that.

Comment: What do you mean? With the if condition?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API scroll down and read Overview. You can only pass 3 variables to the shortcode... `$atts, $content, $tag` where $tag is the shortcode tag.  You have to figure out how to pass the order id in the shortcode as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This code is now working, but only displaying *Pending* status, even when it is not the current status:

```
add_shortcode( 'order_status_custom', 'wpc_orderstatus_shortcode');
function wpc_orderstatus_shortcode( $atts ) {

$order = new WC_Order($post->ID);
$order-> get_id();
if ( $order->has_status('completed') ) {
    $data= 'completed';
} elseif( $order->has_status('on-hold') ){
    $data ='on-hold';
}elseif( $order->has_status('pending') ){
     $data= 'pending';
}elseif( $order->has_status('processing') ){
    $data ='processing';
}else{
    $data = 'Cancelled';
}
    return $data;
}
```